# I'm getting "RVM is not a function" error on Mac OS X, and no posted solutions work

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm on Mac OS x 10.8.2 ("Mountain Lion"), and I successfully installed RVM 1.17.8 and its dependencies. I'm able to use it to install Ruby versions using `rvm install 1.9.2`, but I can't execute `rvm use <version>` without getting this error:

```
RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a example.
```

I have the following in ~/.bash_profile, which I have set to run, using `source ~/.bash_profile`, whenever a terminal window is launched:

```
export SVN_EDITOR=vim
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
[ -r ~/.bashrc ] && source ~/.bashrc
```

I've tried running `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm`, which runs without returning an error, but I still get the "RVM is not a function" error when I try to use RVM to set the Ruby version within the terminal session.

I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling RVM using `rvm implode`. I've run out of ideas and I can't seem to find any more solutions online.  Help?

Comment: Did you read and try the suggestions on the RVM [Help & Support](https://rvm.io/support/) page?

Comment: I thought I'd tried all the posted solutions, but I found something on there under the ".bash_profile not being loaded on OSX" section that fixed it for me. It seems that the whole issue was that I had my terminal set to open with the "default login shell" and when I changed it to instead open with /usr/bash, the source rvm command above worked, and rvm is now being recognized as a function. Thank you!!

Comment: OMG thank you for posting this comment! This was exactly my problem in Terminal settings.

Comment: As of OS X 10.10 Yosemite in Terminal:Preferences:General:Shells open with: /bin/bash  worked for me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The solution ended up being on the RVM [Help & Support](https://rvm.io/support/) page, in the ".bash_profile not being loaded on OSX" section. It seems that the issue was that I had my terminal set to open with the "default login shell" and when I changed it to instead open with the command "/usr/bash" in Preferences/Setup, "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm" started working, and rvm is now being recognized as a function.

Comment: There is no `/usr/bash`, why do you keep saying that?

Comment: On Mac 10.11.2 change "Terminal:Preferences:General:Shells open with:Default login shell" to ""Shells open with:Command (complete path):`/bin/bash`".  This and `rvm get head --auto-dotfiles` fixed the problem for me.  Be sure to **quit and restart** Terminal, for me new login shells created by a new tab didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 30):

Make sure your shell initialization files are set up properly:

```
rvm get head --auto-dotfiles
```

Then go to your terminal emulator preferences and enable **login shell**, sometimes it it required to use `/bin/bash --login`.
Also make sure to fully close terminal and open it fresh after changing the setting.

Comment: This is the best answer. Worked for me on a ubuntu box.

Comment: To be clear in case somebody gets confused like me: on Mac OS X 10.10.5, there is no simple checkbox for "enable login shell".  But it's pretty straightforward: open Terminal preferences and choose "Shells open with:"  option of providing the command.  This is where to use "/bin/bash --login" as the command to start each shell with.

Comment: The error message didn't go away even after executing the above command. Finally, I changed the default command to `zsh --login`. And then the error disappeared.

Comment: @imechemi I am in the same position, but your solution did not work for me either, was there anything else you tried?

Answer (score -3):

look for .profile, if exists, remove it! loof for .zshrc, if exists, remove it! Now, use vi to edit your .bash_profile, add this line

`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`

Now, close all console services and open again, make a test using 
`$ rvm gemset use global`

Work fine for me!

Comment: Delete .zshrc and create .bash_profile? You do realize those are for different shells?