# Running rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, gcc

I am coming up against issues running a rails server on a local environment. I am on Mac OS X 10.10. I think they relate to the osx-gcc-installer.

Running in Terminal:

```
$ rails server
```

Results in:

```
Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 1.9.3
```

Cool, so then I run:

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3-p550
```

Which results in:

```
-bash: rvm: command not found
```

This solves that:

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

So I run this again:

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3-p550
```

Which produces this:

```
Warning, new version of rvm available '1.26.1', you are using older version '1.26.0'.
You can disable this warning with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=0 >> ~/.rvmrc
You can enable  auto-update  with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.10/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p550.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
password required for 'softwareupdate -l': 
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system.....
Installing required packages: gcc48, libyaml, libksba......
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install gcc48 libyaml libksba',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/<user>/.rvm/log/1415842393_ruby-1.9.3-p550/package_install_gcc48_libyaml_libksba.log
++ case "$1" in
++ [[ -t 1 ]]
++ return 1
++ printf %b 'There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.

Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.

Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Installation\n'
There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.

Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.

Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Installation
++ case "$_system_version" in
++ return 1
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

So, as it suggests, I try:

```
brew tap --repair
```

Which says:

```
Pruned 0 dead formulae
Tapped 161 formulae
```

And run:

```
brew doctor
```

Which gives two warnings both mentioning osx-gcc-installer (which I stupidly installed as part of the Team Treehouse instructions for setting up a dev environment):

```
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: You have an outdated version of /usr/bin/install_name_tool installed.
This will cause binary package installations to fail.
This can happen if you install osx-gcc-installer or RailsInstaller.
To restore it, you must reinstall OS X or restore the binary from
the OS packages.

Warning: You seem to have osx-gcc-installer installed.
Homebrew doesn't support osx-gcc-installer. It causes many builds to fail and
is an unlicensed distribution of really old Xcode files.
Please run `xcode-select --install` to install the CLT.
```

I run:

```
xcode-select --install
```

And get this:

```
Usage: xcode-select -print-path
or: xcode-select -switch <xcode_folder_path>
or: xcode-select -version
Arguments:
-print-path                     Prints the path of the current Xcode folder
-switch <xcode_folder_path>     Sets the path for the current Xcode folder
-version                        Prints xcode-select version information
```

Which doesn't seem to have done anything so I fetch the CLT from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action# (which I'm pretty sure I had beforehand), install, and reboot.

Do I really need to reinstall my OS to solve this problem? That seems like overkill and I'm hoping somebody has another solution.

**Update**
On the suggestion of a commenter, I tried this:

```
$ rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

Which returned:

```
RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.
You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for an example.
```

So I tried the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14289460/1644196) and

```
$ source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

And re-ran:

```
$ rvm use 1.9.3
```

Which resulted in

```
ruby-1.9.3-p550 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p550'
```

So I checked which versions I had using

```
$ rvm list
```

And got

```
rvm rubies

ruby-1.9.3-p0-falcon [ x86_64 ]
ruby-1.9.3-p545 [ x86_64 ]
```

Then ran:

```
$ rvm use 1.9.3-p0-falcon --default
```

And tried:

```
$ rails server
```

Which resulted in:

```
Could not find bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

But `bundle install` outputs:

```
/Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0-falcon/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': dlopen(/Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0-falcon/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.1.0/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: @@HOMEBREW_CELLAR@@/openssl/1.0.1j/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
Reason: image not found - /Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0-falcon/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.1.0/openssl.bundle
from /Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0-falcon/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0-falcon/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0-falcon@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:201:in `<class:Persistent>'
from /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0-falcon@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:191:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0-falcon/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0-falcon/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0-falcon@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/vendored_persistent.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0-falcon/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0-falcon/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0-falcon@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0-falcon@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:247:in `install'
from /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0-falcon@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
from /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0-falcon@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:121:in `invoke_command'
from /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0-falcon@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:363:in `dispatch'
from /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0-falcon@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
from /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0-falcon@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:10:in `start'
from /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0-falcon@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0-falcon@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:5:in `with_friendly_errors'
from /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0-falcon@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/bin/bundle:20:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0-falcon@global/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
from /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0-falcon@global/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
from /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0-falcon/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0-falcon/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Which looks a bit more serious, but at least it isn't telling me to reinstall my OS.

Comment: Did you do `rvm use 1.9.3 --default` ?

Comment: @Tomanow, thank you for the comment. Unfortunately, that results in `ruby-1.9.3-p550 is not installed. To install do: rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p550` which is one of the commands that I try above.